# Colocar elementos lado a lado usando HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso colocar o menu centralizado na horizontal  do lado da logo, help!!!

Código até agora:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gabriel Morais</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="1">
        <figure class="header"><img alt="Logo" src="img\logo.png" width="90px" height="90px"></figure>
    </div>

    <div id="2">
        <nav id="header">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Serviços</a>
                        <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Design Gráfico</a></li>                    
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script src="js\script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
    font-family: arial,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.menu {
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;

}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.menu li a {color: black; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 10px; display: block;}


.menu li a:hover{
    background:#333; 
    color:#fff; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc; 
    text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff; 
}

.menu li  ul{
    position:absolute; 
    top:25px; 
    left:0;
    background-color:#fff; 
    display:none;
}  

.menu li:hover ul, .menu li.over ul{display:block;}

.menu li ul li{
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0; 
    display:block; 
    width:150px;
    }

.header {
    margin: 10px;
}

div#1{
    display: inline-block;
}

div#2{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você não precisa dessas divs `id="1"` e `id="2"`. Pode fazer mais simples, nesta estrutura:

```
<header>
   <figure>LOGO</figure>
   <nav>MENU</nav>
</header>
```

Utilize flexbox para alinhar os elementos e esqueça `float: left`. No exemplo abaixo alterei nomes de id's e classes para não confundir as coisas:

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
    font-family: arial,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#menu li {
    position: relative;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#menu li a {color: black; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 10px; display: block;}


#menu li a:hover{
    background:#333; 
    color:#fff; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc; 
    text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff; 
}

#menu li  ul{
    position:absolute; 
    top:25px; 
    left:0;
    background-color:#fff; 
    display:none;
}  

#menu li:hover ul, #menu li.over ul{display:block;}

#menu li ul li{
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0; 
    width:150px;
    }

.logo {
    margin: 10px;
}

header, #menu, #menu ul{
   display: flex;
}

#menu{
   flex: 1; /* isto é para a nav ocupar a largura toda menos a logo */
   justify-content: center; /* alinha horizontalmente */
   align-items: center; /* alinha verticalmente */
}
```

```html
<header>
    <figure class="logo"><img alt="Logo" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" width="90px" height="90px"></figure>

     <nav id="menu">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Serviços</a>
                     <ul>
                           <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Design Gráfico</a></li>                    
                     </ul>
                 </li>
             <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>  
         </ul>
     </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode ser feito facilmente utilizando a propriedade `flexbox` do CSS.

Para isso, fiz uma pequena modificação no seu HTML, colocando a imagem dentro da sua barra de navegação, ficando assim:

```
    <nav id="header">
        <figure class="header">
            <img alt="Logo" src="img\logo.png" width="90px" height="90px">
        </figure>

        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Serviços</a>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Design Gráfico</a></li>                    
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

E é no CSS que a mágica acontece! Eu vou selecionar a barra de navegação e atribuir a propriedade `display: flex` para que os elementos fiquem alinhados lado a lado.

```
nav {
   display: flex;
}
```

Pronto! Isso já deixa ambos lado a lado. Vou deixar um link também em português falando um pouco mais sobre o Flexbox do CSS, segue: https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/

Apenas mais uma observação, tome cuidado com os nomes que você dá para seus ID's e classes, isso pode causar muita dor de cabeça pra você no futuro, pois reparei que o nome do `id` da sua `nav` é *header*, que é o mesmo nome que a `class` da `figure` em que sua logo está dentro.

Espero que tenha ajudado, abraços!